# Why is the tension force tangential to the string in a string wave?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, string

Many derivations and concepts regarding string waves have this kind of diagram:[image: Tenssion force in a string during wave traveling]

Where it describes that the tension force is tangential to the string curve. I didn't find the reason for this or maybe I do not know something preceding concept. Can you please provide me the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tension force is applied to this element of the string by the next element of the string.

Since the next element exists along the length of the string and not off to the side of the string, then along the length is the only direction that it can apply a force.